# Using mean value theorem .

Tags: real-analysis

True false justify.

Let $f$: $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\ $,and $S \subset \mathbb{R}$. 
If the derivative of $f$ on  $S$ is equal to zero then $f$ is constant on $S$?
Can we use M.V.T to solve this problem, and if we can't I need a hint.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming $S$ is an interval**

Hint:  Suppose that $f(x)$ is not constant on $S$.  Then take two points $a<b$ (both in $S$) where $f(a)\neq f(b)$.  Apply MVT and get a point where the derivative is not zero in $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the [Heaviside function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), that is $0$ for negative $x$ and $1$ for positive $x$.  Set $S=(-3,-1)\cup(1,3)$.  The Heaviside derivative is zero on all of $S$, yet is not constant on all of $S$.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is only true for path connected $S$ and $f$ continuous on $S$. (equivalently in $\mathbb R$: $S$ is an interval)

If both things are satisfied, the FTC gives you
$$f(t) = \int_a^t f'(s) \ \mathrm ds + f(a) = f(a)$$
As long as $S = [a,b]$ and $t\in S$. Wheter $a\in S$ or $b\in S$ is irrelevant (i.e. the openness)